# R graph: label by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data I am working on is a clustering data, with multiple observations within one group, I generated a caterpillar plot and want labelling for each group(zipid), not every line, my current graph and code look like this:

```
  text = hosp_new[,c("zipid")]
  ggplot(hosp_new, aes(x = id, y = oe, colour = zipid, shape = group)) +
  # theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 2, 4)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = low_ci, ymax = high_ci)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start_id, xend = end_id, y = region_oe, yend = region_oe, linetype = "4", size = 1.2)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = region_low_ci, ymax = region_high_ci), alpha=0.2, linetype = "blank") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1, alpha = 0.2, colour = "red", size = 1), show.legend = "FALSE") +
  scale_size_identity() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "hospital id", breaks = seq(0,210, by = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "O:E ratio", breaks = seq(0,7, by = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = text), position = position_stack(vjust = 10.0), size = 2)
```

Caterpillar plot:

[image: caterpillar plot]

Each color represents a region, I just want one label/per region, but don't know how to delete the duplicated labels in this graph. 
Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that in the `r` tag you must provide fully reproducible, runnable code/data in your example, including library statements, example data, etc. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You could create a second dataframe with the label and the midpoint of each hospital id, and pass that to geom_text, or you could use facets, or... But for more specific help, a small example dataset should be added - ie an example of hosp_new with only a few hospital id's: like adding the results of `dput(droplevels(hosp_new[hosp_new$id %in% sample(hosp_new$id, 3), ]))` to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to have `geom_text` return only one value for each `zipid`, rather than multiple values. If we want each `zipid` label located in the middle of its group, then we can use the average value of `id` as the x-coordinate for each label. In the code below, we use `stat_summaryh` (from the `ggstance` package) to calculate that average `id` value for the x-coordinate of the label and return a single label for each `zipid`.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(ggstance)

# Fake data
set.seed(300)
dat = data.frame(id=1:100, y=cumsum(rnorm(100)), 
                 zipid=rep(LETTERS[1:10], c(10, 5, 20, 8, 7, 12, 7, 10, 13,8)))

ggplot(dat, aes(id, y, colour=zipid)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=id, yend=0)) +
  stat_summaryh(fun.x=mean, aes(label=zipid, y=1.02*max(y)), geom="text") +
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

You could also use faceting, as mentioned by @user20650. In the code below, `panel.spacing.x=unit(0,'pt')` removes the space between facet panels, while `expand=c(0,0.5)` adds 0.5 units of padding on the sides of each panel. Together, these ensure constant spacing between tick marks, even across facets.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(id, y, colour=zipid)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=id, yend=0)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ zipid, scales="free_x", space="free_x") +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:nrow(dat), 
                     labels=c(rbind(seq(0,100,5),'','','',''))[1:(nrow(dat)+1)], 
                     expand=c(0,0.5)) +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0,"pt"))
```

[image]